# Regular expression for phonenumber

Tags: regex

I need such regex to match such string

```
+68 0315 556 918
```

May be someone may help

Basically i think i just need to check if string contains `+ space and digits`?

Comment: Good source for learning regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Please be more specific about what to match. E.g. `/\+68 0315 556 918/` would match such string.

Comment: You haven't given enough information about what you want the regex to match. `/\+68 0315 556 918/` is a suitable regex for this question. You need to give us more cases / requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your request: If you want to check whether a string starts with a plus and contains only spaces and numbers afterwards you can use e.g.

```
/^\+[0-9 ]+$/
```

Note: this will also match e.g. `"+ 9"` or `"+ "`, so please take care about the specific details of your requirements.

- if space is optional you can use `/^\+?[0-9 ]+$/`.
- if you do insist on at least one digit use `/^\+[0-9 ]*[0-9][0-9 ]*$/`.
- if there may be at most on space delimiter use `/^\+([0-9]+ )*[0-9]+$/`.

Answer (score 1):

A string containing only plus signs, spaces, and digits is matched by:

```
^[+ \d]*$
```

Depending on what language / engine you're using the regex in `\d` may not be valid. You could replace it by `0-9` instead in that case. Some languages might also require delimiters in which case:

```
/^[+ 0-9]$/ will work.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to implore you to read up on regular expressions. If you like learning from books, I'd suggest Regular Expression Cookbook (pretty sure it has Jeff Atwood's seal of approval). Regardless, I'll offer a precise (though not as literal as the other answers) solution. You must turn enable whitespace mode (`x` in Perl and many others) for this one:

```
/^\+[0-9]{2} \s+ # the first two digits
[0-9]{4} \s+ # the second set of digits
[0-9]{3} \s+ # the third set of digits
[0-9]{4}$/x # the final set of digits
```

As you see, I suggest being explicit in your regex and make sure you're matching *exactly* what you want to match. Simply matching a string that contains a plus, spaces and digits might result in strings that are very much not phone numbers!